# Error while creating JAXB classes from WSDL

Tags: jaxb, wsdl, schema, xjc

First of all,I have just started working on web services and I am stuck in the first step i.e creating the java classes from the provided wsdl/xsd . I am running the following ant task to create java classes and wrapp them up in the jar file in the given location.

**Error :**

```
[xjc] [ERROR] s4s-elt-schema-ns: The namespace of element 'definitions' must be from the schema namespace, 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.
      [xjc]   line 2 of file:/Users/deblinakarmakar/Desktop/work/Wland/wonderland/hybris/bin/custom/wonderlandcore/resources/taxware/BatchTaxCalculationManagerService.wsdl
      [xjc] 
      [xjc] [ERROR] s4s-elt-invalid: Element 'definitions' is not a valid element in a schema document.
      [xjc]   line 2 of file:/Users/deblinakarmakar/Desktop/work/Wland/wonderland/hybris/bin/custom/wonderlandcore/resources/taxware/BatchTaxCalculationManagerService.wsdl
```

**This is my WSDL file :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://ws.taxware.com/service" xmlns:wns="http://ws.taxware.com/service" xmlns:tns="http://ws.taxwareenterprise.com" xmlns:ens="http://ws.taxware.com/exception" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

 <wsdl:types>
  <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://ws.taxwareenterprise.com" elementFormDefault="qualified">

   <!-- This schema import is for the common complex types for both batch and tax. -->
   <!-- PLEASE DO NOT OVVERRIDE THIS WSDL FILE WITH ANY COMMON COMPLEX TYPE USED BY BOTH TAX AND BATCH WSDLs -->
   <import namespace="http://ws.taxwareenterprise.com" schemaLocation="TaxBatchCommon.xsd"/>
   <import namespace="http://ws.taxwareenterprise.com" schemaLocation="BatchTaxCalculationTypes.xsd"/>

  <xs:element name="batchCalculateDocumentRequest" type="tns:BatchTaxCalculationRequest"/>
  <xs:element name="batchCalculateDocumentRequestResponse"/>
  <xs:element name="cancelBatchRequestResponse"/>
  <xs:element name="endBatchRequestResponse"/>
  <xs:element name="cancelBatchRequest" type="tns:BatchIdRequest"/>
  <xs:element name="endBatchRequest" type="tns:BatchIdRequest"/>
  <xs:element name="removeBatchResultsRequest" type="tns:BatchIdRequest"/>
  <xs:element name="getBatchExceptionsRequest" type="tns:BatchIdRangeRequest"/>
  <xs:element name="getBatchExceptionsResponse" type="tns:ExceptionsResponse"/>
  <xs:element name="getBatchResultsRequest" type="tns:BatchIdRangeRequest"/>
  <xs:element name="getBatchResultsResponse" type="tns:GetBatchResultsResponse"/>
  <xs:element name="getBatchSuccessCountRequest" type="tns:BatchIdRequest"/>
  <xs:element name="getBatchSuccessCountResponse" type="tns:CountResponse"/>
  <xs:element name="isBatchCompleteRequest" type="tns:BatchIdRequest"/>
  <xs:element name="isBatchCompleteResponse" type="tns:IsBatchCompleteResponse"/>
  <xs:element name="startBatchRequest" type="tns:StartBatchRequest"/>
  <xs:element name="startBatchResponse" type="tns:BatchIdResponse"/>
  </schema>
 </wsdl:types>


 <wsdl:message name="cbRequest">
   <wsdl:part name="request" element="tns:cancelBatchRequest"/>
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="cbResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="request" element="tns:cancelBatchRequestResponse"/>
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="ebRequest">
   <wsdl:part name="request" element="tns:endBatchRequest"/>
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="ebResponse">
   <wsdl:part name="request" element="tns:endBatchRequestResponse"/>
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="bcdRequest">
   <wsdl:part name="request" element="tns:batchCalculateDocumentRequest"/>
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="bcdResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="request" element="tns:batchCalculateDocumentRequestResponse"/>
 </wsdl:message>


 <wsdl:message name="gbeRequest">
  <wsdl:part name="request" element="tns:getBatchExceptionsRequest"/>
 </wsdl:message>

 <wsdl:message name="gbeResponse">
  <wsdl:part name="result" element="tns:getBatchExceptionsResponse"/>
 </wsdl:message>

 <wsdl:message name="gbrRequest">
  <wsdl:part name="request" element="tns:getBatchResultsRequest"/>
 </wsdl:message>

 <wsdl:message name="gbrResponse">
  <wsdl:part name="result" element="tns:getBatchResultsResponse"/>
 </wsdl:message>


 <wsdl:message name="gbscRequest">
  <wsdl:part name="request" element="tns:getBatchSuccessCountRequest"/>
 </wsdl:message>

 <wsdl:message name="gbscResponse">
  <wsdl:part name="result" element="tns:getBatchSuccessCountResponse"/>
 </wsdl:message>


 <wsdl:message name="ibcRequest">
  <wsdl:part name="request" element="tns:isBatchCompleteRequest"/>
 </wsdl:message>

 <wsdl:message name="ibcResponse">
  <wsdl:part name="result" element="tns:isBatchCompleteResponse"/>
 </wsdl:message>

 <wsdl:message name="rbrRequest">
  <wsdl:part name="request" element="tns:removeBatchResultsRequest"/>
 </wsdl:message>


 <wsdl:message name="sbRequest">
  <wsdl:part name="request" element="tns:startBatchRequest"/>
 </wsdl:message>

 <wsdl:message name="sbResponse">
  <wsdl:part name="result" element="tns:startBatchResponse"/>
 </wsdl:message>

 <wsdl:message name="twFault">
  <wsdl:part name="fault" element="tns:tweFault"/>
 </wsdl:message>

 <wsdl:portType name="BatchTaxCalculationManagerServiceInterface">
 <wsdl:operation name="calculateDocument">
    <wsdl:input message="wns:bcdRequest"/>
    <wsdl:fault name="twFault" message="wns:twFault"/>
  </wsdl:operation>

   <wsdl:operation name="cancelBatch">
    <wsdl:input message="wns:cbRequest"/>
    <wsdl:fault name="twFault" message="wns:twFault"/>
   </wsdl:operation>

   <wsdl:operation name="endBatch">
    <wsdl:input message="wns:ebRequest"/>
    <wsdl:fault name="twFault" message="wns:twFault"/>
   </wsdl:operation>

   <wsdl:operation name="getBatchExceptions">
    <wsdl:input message="wns:gbeRequest"/>
    <wsdl:output message="wns:gbeResponse"/>
    <wsdl:fault name="twFault" message="wns:twFault"/>
   </wsdl:operation>

   <wsdl:operation name="getBatchResults">
    <wsdl:input message="wns:gbrRequest"/>
    <wsdl:output message="wns:gbrResponse"/>
    <wsdl:fault name="twFault" message="wns:twFault"/>
   </wsdl:operation>

   <wsdl:operation name="getBatchSuccessCount">
    <wsdl:input message="wns:gbscRequest"/>
    <wsdl:output message="wns:gbscResponse"/>
    <wsdl:fault name="twFault" message="wns:twFault"/>
   </wsdl:operation>

   <wsdl:operation name="isBatchComplete">
    <wsdl:input message="wns:ibcRequest"/>
    <wsdl:output message="wns:ibcResponse"/>
    <wsdl:fault name="twFault" message="wns:twFault"/>
   </wsdl:operation>

   <wsdl:operation name="removeBatchResults">
    <wsdl:input message="wns:rbrRequest"/>
     <!--<wsdl:output message="wns:ibcResponse"/>-->
    <wsdl:fault name="twFault" message="wns:twFault"/>
   </wsdl:operation>

   <wsdl:operation name="startBatch">
    <wsdl:input message="wns:sbRequest"/>
    <wsdl:output message="wns:sbResponse"/>
    <wsdl:fault name="twFault" message="wns:twFault"/>
  </wsdl:operation>

 </wsdl:portType>

 <wsdl:binding name="BatchTaxCalculationManagerServiceSoapBinding" type="wns:BatchTaxCalculationManagerServiceInterface">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="calculateDocument">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://ws.taxwareenterprise.com/calculateDocument"  style="document" /> 
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:input>
         <wsdl:fault name="twFault">
            <soap:fault name="twFault" use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:fault>   
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="cancelBatch">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://ws.taxwareenterprise.com/cancelBatch"  style="document" />   
        <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:fault name="twFault">
        <soap:fault name="twFault" use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:fault>   
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="endBatch">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://ws.taxwareenterprise.com/endBatch"  style="document" />  
        <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:fault name="twFault">
        <soap:fault name="twFault" use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:fault>   
     </wsdl:operation>

     <wsdl:operation name="getBatchExceptions">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://ws.taxwareenterprise.com/getBatchExceptions"  style="document" />
        <wsdl:input>
              <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:output>
         <wsdl:fault name="twFault">
            <soap:fault name="twFault" use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:fault>
     </wsdl:operation>

     <wsdl:operation name="getBatchResults">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://ws.taxwareenterprise.com/getBatchResults"  style="document" />
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:output>
         <wsdl:fault name="twFault">
            <soap:fault name="twFault" use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:fault>
     </wsdl:operation>

     <wsdl:operation name="getBatchSuccessCount">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://ws.taxwareenterprise.com/getBatchSuccessCount"  style="document" />
        <wsdl:input>
              <soap:body use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:output>
         <wsdl:fault name="twFault">
            <soap:fault name="twFault" use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:fault>
     </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="isBatchComplete">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://ws.taxwareenterprise.com/isBatchComplete"  style="document" />
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:output>
         <wsdl:fault name="twFault">
            <soap:fault name="twFault" use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="removeBatchResults">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://ws.taxwareenterprise.com/removeBatchResults"  style="document" />
        <wsdl:input>
             <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:input>
         <wsdl:fault name="twFault">
            <soap:fault name="twFault" use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="startBatch">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://ws.taxwareenterprise.com/startBatch"  style="document" />
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:output>
         <wsdl:fault name="twFault">
            <soap:fault name="twFault" use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>

  <wsdl:service name="BatchTaxCalculationManagerServiceService">
   <wsdl:port name="BatchTaxCalculationManagerService" binding="wns:BatchTaxCalculationManagerServiceSoapBinding">
    <soap:address location="http://localhost:8086/twe/services/BatchTaxCalculationManagerService"/>
   </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey thanks for your answer,but I have resolved this myself.Problem was with my ant task.
                Generating Authentication service JAXB for Taxware from wsdl

```
            <property name="taxware.schema.dir" location="${wonderlandcore}/resources/taxcalculation" />
            <make_jaxb_jar extname="wonderlandcore"
                    package="org.wonderlandcore.taxcalculation.jaxb"
                    schemadir="${taxware.schema.dir}"
                    bindingdir="${taxware.schema.dir}"
                    includes="**/*.wsdl"
                    excludes=""
                    destjarname="taxware_calculation"
                    xjc-arg="-wsdl"
                     />
    </target>
```

I missed the "xjc-arg="-wsdl" earlier,so the task wasn't set for wsdl. Works fine now.